# Why do films sometimes transpose everything by a quarter step?

Tags: transposition

Sometimes when playing along to music, you notice that the recording is transposed not by a semitone or a whole tone (whereby you could just play along on any normally tuned instrument), but by an interval that requires tuning down/up by a quarter tone. I have noticed that it is commonly found in movies.

**My question is, quite simply: why?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

log (25 / 24) / log (2) * 1200 = 70.67, so the conversion of a standard movie (24 frames per second), to be broadcast on European TV (25 frames per second) will shift all pitches up 70 cents; that's one common situation that you may be referring to.

Answer (score 17):

It's probably not transposed, but speeded up or slowed down by a little bit. Sometimes to fit exactly into a sequence, sometimes changed to fit better with the mood of the film at that point. With digital sound, nowadays, this is not a necessary operation to do, as the tempo can be altered without affecting the pitch. Previously, to slow a piece down (to make if fit a longer scene), would have dropped its pitch, maybe by as little as you've found.

Answer (score 12):

What user12864 said, it's the [PAL speedup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/576i#PAL_speed-up).

Luckily, these days it's easy to reverse by telling your movie player to play at 96% (24/25) speed.

THX films correct the pitch, by the way.